# How to add dynamically created link in React

Tags: reactjs

```
   moveToListSuccess = (listMovedTo, listMovedId) => {
    const link = <a href={`/mylist?id=${listMovedId}`}>{listMovedTo}</a>;
    this.showTopMessage('success', `1 item successfully moved to ${link}`);
    this.getSavedListAction();
}

showTopMessage = (type, message) => {
    this.setState({
        showMessage: true,
        message,
        type,
    });
}
```

It gives me [Object object] when i try and pass link as a parameter since its string concatenation

**When the user clicks the link he/she should navigate to page.**

[image]

And message is being passed here in render

```
  {showMessage && <div className={cx('topLevelMessage')}>
                <MessageBox showIcon={false} hasClose type={type} level="section" onClose={this.closeMessageBox}>
                    <span>{`${message}`}</span>
                </MessageBox>
            </div>}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please provide more info.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. it is very unclear

Comment: added details @Arseniy-II

Comment: @vini template literals takes primitive types. it doesn't work well with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template literals takes primitive types. It doesn't work well with objects

To fix your problem, use a third argument and pass the `link` object

```
moveToListSuccess = (listMovedTo, listMovedId) => {
    const link = <a href={`/mylist?id=${listMovedId}`}>{listMovedTo}</a>;
    this.showTopMessage('success', "1 item successfully moved to ",link );
    this.getSavedListAction();
}
```

i wouldn't recommend this approach, but i've provided solution without changing any of your current flow. Set `link` object to your `state` as shown below

```
showTopMessage = (type, message,link) => {
    this.setState({
        showMessage: true,
        message,
        type,
        link
    });
}
```

You can render as shown below

```
{showMessage && <div className={cx('topLevelMessage')}>
    <MessageBox showIcon={false} hasClose type={type} level="section" onClose={this.closeMessageBox}>
        <span>{message} {link}</span>
    </MessageBox>
</div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

If U want to display a HTML tag in like a string variable. U can use this lib [React render html](https://github.com/utatti/react-render-html#readme) to render your string html.

```
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';

{showMessage && <div className={cx('topLevelMessage')}>
   <MessageBox showIcon={false} hasClose type={type} level="section" onClose={this.closeMessageBox}>
       <span>{renderHTML(message)}</span>
   </MessageBox>
</div>}
```